# Wordpress Rest Api rest_cannot_edit

Tags: rest-api, post-editor

Hello I want to edit the post by rest api.  i login succesfully with admin access but still i get

when logging in i get response

```
{'success': True,
 'redirectTo': 'https://cannedsplam.com/wp-admin/'}
```

But when i need to edit i cannot

```
{'code': 'rest_cannot_edit',
 'message': 'Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.',
 'data': {'status': 401}}
```

the endpoint is `/wp-json/ldlms/v1/sfwd-topic/291`

and the plugin is **LearnDash Lms**

Comment: You'll have to ask this of LearnDash's support. [Third-party plugin support is off topic here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I also tried the same with pages endpoint the same i got.